# How to make Animated Android Live Wallpaper?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Can anyone suggest me of any step by step tutorials on how to make and Android LiveWallpaper. I am not able to find any good tutorials and I am sort of new to this.

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/02/live-wallpapers.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at this article from Vogella:
http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Start at: 2. Android Wallpaper Example

Read the complete tutorial slowly and carefully (helps a lot).

Comment: Link doesn't seem to work anymore - [this is the last capture in archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122051501/http://www.vogella.com:80/tutorials/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html)