# How do I create an application without a main activity in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, live-wallpaper

I am creating a live wallpaper in android studio. I do not want any UI besides the wallpaper, so my application contains no activities.

However, when I try to deploy to a device, I get the following error and my wallpaper will not load.

```
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity
```

How can I create an application which works that does not have a main activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Animated Android Live Wallpaper ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584791/how-to-make-animated-android-live-wallpaper)

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek That isn't a duplicate. The linked tutorial has a main activity which sets the wallpaper. I want to have no main activity.

Comment: Why are you reluctant to create a main activity? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @kha Because I don't need one. It seems odd that I need to create a main activity which does nothing then exits. If I have to I will, but I'm just checking that I actually have to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to have no activities in your application. The build succeeds, Android Studio only fails when it tries to run it, because it doesn't know what to do.

You need to modify your run configuration. Go to "Run > Edit configurations" and under "Launch options" change "Default Activity" to "Nothing":

[image]

Comment: Where do I find the "Run configuration" menu?

Comment: Go to "Run > Edit configurations".

Comment: But when would this be useful? Let us say we want to start a service, I would code for it in Activity, is it just possible to make it invisible?